# CMS Page URL from ID in phtml (M2)

Tags: magento2, php, phtml, cms-pages

In a page template (.phtml) file, we can generate a link to *another* `CMS page` using the following snippet:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('my_page_url_key');?>">Link to my page</a>
```

But is it possible to have a link generated if we know the ID of the page? Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(3);?>">Link to my page with ID 3</a>
```

This way the admin can change url key without breaking the theme links.

Comment: @Rakesh Not at all. I'm not asking for the current page! There is a hint in your answer, though: `$page = $this->pageRepository->getById($pageId);
$url = $page->getIdentifier();`which I will try.

Comment: @Rakesh No, the block I'm using doesn't implement the pageReposity class. I could overload the class with my own, I suppose, but that's overkill for just one link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using object manager you can get **CMS page url**, if you have **already id of cms page.**

```
$pageId = 1;
$this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

or 

$this->_objectManager = $block->_objectManager;
$CMSPageURL = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Helper\Page')
->getPageUrl($pageId);
```

you can call object manager in your block using

```
protected $_objectManager;
public function __construct( 
... 
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager, 
... ) { 
      ... 
      $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager; 
      ... 
}
```

You can also use a helper like this, as this can be used without needing the objectManager:

```
$pageHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Cms\Helper\Page');
$pageHelper->getPageUrl('my-page-id');
```

May be it will help you, thanks.

Comment: This works! :) But I'm worried about using the objectManager like that, as I've read that it's discouraged?

Comment: if you have used custom block then you can call block variable of object manager, like $block->_objectManager in phtml;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, array $data = array()) {
     $this->_objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
or
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    ...
) 
{
    ...
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    ...
}

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, @chirag I'm marking your reply as the answer. I will use your suggestion as it's the best one I've seen so far, and doesn't look that offensive. I'd be happy for someone to explain when it's okay to use the object manager, and when it's not!

Comment: For everyone who thinks this is a good example - it's not.
Instead of declaring object manager in the constructor  - declare object that you want to call, in this case 'Magento\Cms\Helper\Page'.
Moreover - do not call/declare objectmanager if you do not know how it is need to be used.

Comment: You can also declare "Magento\Cms\Helper\Page" this class in block constructor.